# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have authorization window. When app is starting it is okey. I tap sign in and go to the next window. But when I tap sign out and want to back at authorization window - I get nil. In the method signinView controller is nil.

[image]

Comment: Please post your [mcve] as text marked up as code and not a picture.  Making it a picture prevents us from copying and pasting the code and diminishes our ability to help you.

Comment: you provide huge amount of information , we can't just assume that how you showing your view controller . please post code

Comment: The most important thing is that you shouldn't access storyboard like this:
`self.window?.rootViewController!.storyboard?`. This is the worst approach i have ever seen. if anything is nil, either application will crash (to unwrap)

Answer (score 8):

you need to take instance from Storyboard.

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“MyController”)
```

In this way you will get your controller instance.

Make sure you already set storyboard ID for this controller.

[image]

Comment: I met this when I'm mixed to use IB and coding programmatically. In some pure code VC, I need to declare the storyboard then to instantiate another VC, otherwize that vc will not be opened.

Answer (score 1):

**Just replace below code in function's second line and hope it will solved your problem.**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)//Make it global
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("your identifer")
```